# Assign a pattern to the whole page but reveal it only on some shapes, the rest should be black

Tags: css, svg, textures, mask

I would like to create a web page where the background is flat black but I need to add also a background pattern that should be visible only inside some shapes (circles in this simple example, but they will be a complicated path, different for each section).

I know I could assign the pattern to the shapes, but I need also to animate the shapes and is not possible to animate the pattern.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/background-pattern-sw1zx?file=/src/App.js) my starting code

I applied a texture in CSS to the entire page and I add some circles.
Now I need to "hide" the texture everywhere except inside the shapes. And the page background should be black.
How can I do that?

Comment: Not very sure what you'd like to achieve but why don't you do the opposite - to place the pattern only inside the shapes?

Comment: @Azu thak you. I thought about that but I can't because in the future, when the use scrolls between sections, the shapes should do a morphological transition (position, color and pattern) that I don't think is possible

Comment: Draw a black background rect then the stuff you want without using a pattern at all and use a clipPath to reveal the bits of stuff you want to display.

Comment: @RobertLongson so you mean to do the pattern in svg? A big long svg

Comment: I mean unless something is repeating, a pattern is not the right answer at all.

Comment: Sorry @RobertLongson, I didn't understand. what you suggest?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's not clear to me whan you say "a pattern is not the right answer at all". 
I have something that is repeating so I think I need a pattern.
The problem is that I need to cover it with black outside shapes and show it only inside shapes

Comment: "different for each section" is why I'm questioning whether a pattern is what you want/need.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh sorry. Each section has a shape (a `path` svg tag) that is different from other sections. The pattern is always the same. When user scrolls between sections, the shapes should do a morphological transition so what have to change are the attributes `d` and `fill` (pattern included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are after?

```css
/* hide the SVG */
svg#pattern {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}


body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 2000px;
  color: white;
}

section {
  height: 400px;
}

circle {
  animation: throb 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes throb {
  0% { r: 48px; }
  50% { r: 30px; }
  100% { r: 48px; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="pattern">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="check" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="10" height="10" fill="linen"/>
      <rect width="5" height="5" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="black"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>


<div>
  <h1>Test page</h1>

  <section>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="url(#check)"/>
    </svg>
  </section>

  <section>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="url(#check)"/>
    </svg>
  </section>

  <section>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="url(#check)"/>
    </svg>
  </section>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
    background-color: black;    
}
.container {
    opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, black 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, black 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(315deg, black 25%, #e5e5f7 25%);
        background-position: 10px 0, 10px 0, 0 0, 0 0;
        background-size: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style='clip-path: url("#test");'></div>
    
<svg x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="test">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the background should be black. Everything outside the circle should be black, the shape should be filled using a pattern

Comment: I've changed the background to black.

Comment: I need something more complicated.
The circle/shape position have not to be so fixed, it depends on the page content and using this solution I think is not possibile to do a morphological transition